# How to use particular field of a model into another model, like I want to use sku as a foreign key in next model?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price=models.IntegerField()
    no=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True)
    sku= models.CharField(max_length=100,default=0,null=True )
```

#Here I want to use sku into another model as a foreign key

Comment: In that case, the `sku` needs to be unique, and non-nullable, since otherwise it can not refer to a product properly.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but I wanted to know the way after making sku unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, the `sku` needs to be unique, and non-nullable, since otherwise it can not refer to a product properly, so:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    no = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Then you can work with the [**`to_field=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field):

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, to_field='sku', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then if you use `my_order.product_id`, it will contain the `sku` of the product it refers to.